# Group Facebook likes on canonical url

Tags: facebook, grouping, facebook-like, canonical-link

I run a Magento site and as such there are several ways to get to the same product where my like button is.

Now for an example:

> www.mysite.co.uk/cat1/product1.html

is the same product as:

> www.mysite.co.uk/cat2/product1.html

just in a different category.

But I want someone who likes this product on **www.mysite.co.uk/cat1/product1.html** to also be applied to **www.mysite.co.uk/cat2/product1.html**

So if 2 separate people click like on the separate pages it should come up with 2 likes rather than 1 like on each page.

I thought if I forced the url with:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.co.uk/product1.html"/>
```

this would work but it doesn't; the canonical urls both use:

http://www.mysite.co.uk/product1.html

where the product can be viewed also.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ever found a solution here?

Comment: If memory serves I don't think I found a solution. However my advice would be to give it 48 hours and check to see if it has worked as I seem to remeber some latency.

Comment: I actually found the solution. Go use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and "Fetch new scrape information' ... there you can see if it's the right information facebook gets.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to have a single canonical product page (say, `http://www.mysite.co.uk/products/product1.html`) and as many pages as you want which point to it, each can be in a different category (i.e., both `/cat1/product1.html` and `/cat2/product1.html` will have `/products/product1.html` as their canonical URL).

For an example, see how these two pages [[a](http://yaniv.aknin.name/so-8069284/a.html), [b](http://yaniv.aknin.name/so-8069284/b.html)], each with a different URL and different content, share their likes by referring to a [canonical page](http://yaniv.aknin.name/so-8069284/canonical.html).

I'm not sure how to go about implementing this with Magento, but with a typical dynamic web development framework like Rails or Django setting something like this up should be fairly easy.